# Can't Input Tab Delimited file to Stanford Classifier

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, csv

I'm having a problem inputting tab delimited files into the [stanford classifier](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml).

Although I was able to successfully walk through all the included stanford tutorials, including the newsgroup tutorial, when I try to input my own training and test data it doesn't load properly.

At first I thought the problem was that I was saving the data into a tab delimited file using an Excel spreadsheet and it was some kind of encoding issue.

But then I got exactly the same results when I did the following. First I literally typed the  demo data below into gedit, making sure to use a tab between the politics/sports class and the ensuing text:

```
politics    Obama today announced a new immigration policy.
sports  The NBA all-star game was last weekend. 
politics    Both parties are eyeing the next midterm elections.
politics    Congress votes tomorrow on electoral reforms.
sports  The Lakers lost again last night, 102-100.
politics    The Supreme Court will rule on gay marriage this spring.
sports  The Red Sox report to spring training in two weeks.
sports  Messi set a world record for goals in a calendar year in 2012.
politics    The Senate will vote on a new budget proposal next week.
politics    The President declared on Friday that he will veto any budget that doesn't include revenue increases.
```

I saved that as `myproject/demo-train.txt` and a similar file as `myproject/demo-test.txt`.

I then ran the following:

```
java -mx1800m -cp stanford-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier 
-trainFile myproject/demo-train.txt -testFile myproject/demo-test.txt
```

The good news: this actually ran without throwing any errors.

The bad news: since it doesn't extract any features, it can't actually estimate a real model and the probability defaults to `1/n` for each item, where `n` is the number of classes.

So then I ran the same command but with two basic options specified:

```
java -mx1800m -cp stanford-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier 
-trainFile myproject/demo-train.txt -testFile myproject/demo-test.txt -2.useSplitWords =2.splitWordsRegexp "\s+"
```

That yielded:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Training dataset could not be processed
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.readDataset(ColumnDataClassifier.java:402)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.readTrainingExamples  (ColumnDataClassifier.java:317)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.trainClassifier(ColumnDataClassifier.java:1652)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.main(ColumnDataClassifier.java:1628)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.makeDatum(ColumnDataClassifier.java:670)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.makeDatumFromLine(ColumnDataClassifier.java:267)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier.makeDatum(ColumnDataClassifier.java:396)
    ... 3 more
```

These are exactly the same results I get when I used the real data I saved from Excel.

Even more though, I don't know how to make sense of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. When I used `readline` in python to print out the raw strings for both the demo files I created and the tutorial files that worked, nothing about the formatting seemed different. So I don't know why this exception would be raised with one set of files but not the other.

Finally, one other quirk. At one point I thought maybe line breaks were the problem. So I deleted all line breaks from the demo files while preserving tab breaks and ran the same command:

```
java -mx1800m -cp stanford-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier 
-trainFile myproject/demo-train.txt -testFile myproject/demo-test.txt -2.useSplitWords =2.splitWordsRegexp "\s+"
```

Surprisingly, this time no java exceptions are thrown. But again, it's worthless: it treats the entire file as one observation, and can't properly fit a model as a result.

I've spent 8 hours on this now and have exhausted everything I can think of. I'm new to Java but I don't think that should be an issue here -- according to Stanford's [API documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html) for `ColumnDataClassifier`, all that's required is a tab delimited file.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

---

One last note: I've run these same commands with the same files on both Windows and Ubuntu, and the results are the same in each.

Comment: I'm looking to duplicate your problem in some attempt to help you, and I feel bad asking you for more information since you've already provided so much already. :)  But where is the tutorial you're following here?  I think I'll need demo-train.txt and demo-test.txt in order to duplicate this.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @dmn. You can find the files [here](http://chrismeserole.com/assets/stanford-classifier-files.zip), it's a zip file with my demo files, the files I actually want to use, and the tutorial files that worked. The tutorial itself is on the [Stanford wiki here](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier/20_Newsgroups). Thank you so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

Use a properties file. In the example [Stanford classifier example](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier/20_Newsgroups)

```
trainFile=20news-bydate-devtrain-stanford-classifier.txt
testFile=20news-bydate-devtest-stanford-classifier.txt
2.useSplitWords=true
2.splitWordsTokenizerRegexp=[\\p{L}][\\p{L}0-9]*|(?:\\$ ?)?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?%?|\\s+|[\\x80-\\uFFFD]|.
2.splitWordsIgnoreRegexp=\\s+
```

The number 2 at the start of lines 3, 4 and 5 signifies the column in your tsv file. So in your case you would use

```
trainFile=20news-bydate-devtrain-stanford-classifier.txt
testFile=20news-bydate-devtest-stanford-classifier.txt
1.useSplitWords=true
1.splitWordsTokenizerRegexp=[\\p{L}][\\p{L}0-9]*|(?:\\$ ?)?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?%?|\\s+|[\\x80-\\uFFFD]|.
1.splitWordsIgnoreRegexp=\\s+
```

or if you want to run with command line arguments

```
java -mx1800m -cp stanford-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -trainFile myproject/demo-train.txt -testFile myproject/demo-test.txt -1.useSplitWords =1.splitWordsRegexp "\s+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same error as you.

Pay attention on tabs in the text you are classifying.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

This means, that at some point classifier expects array of 3 elements, after it splits the string with tabs.

I've run a method, that counts amount of tabs in each line, and if at some line you have not two of them - here is an error.